# three.js new version 99 and morphanimation

Tags: three.js

Is the new skinnedMesh assumed to work also with both skeleton animation and morphTargets ? I updated my software to work with R99 , bones animation is OK  but get TypeError: attribute.onUploadCallback is not a function in the render loop (createBuffer function) when morphTarget included.

Comment: Can you please demonstrate the issue with a [live example](https://jsfiddle.net/f2Lommf5/)?

Comment: this would not be easy. I use an existing json model working well with r98, load it with the legacy json.loader, create the buffergeometry from geometry and modified my application  such as to still have access to former attributes for compatibility with my existing functions. My application is too large for short and simple demo.  So if I'm the only one with such an issue I will further investigate what is happening in the "render ... create Buffer" functions in three.js and update this question when I find more out. Of course the problem can be in my modifications, so I have to dig into ...

Comment: Sorry, mistake was on my side. I was manipulating morphAttributes.position in a way which was OK with R98 but not with R99.